# Flutter: How to add many fields in firestore using one document without overwriting

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a problem on my project right now. I know, many already posted this issue but I really dont know how to implement it in my code. I want to do is, to add multiple data in firestore fields using one document. In the fields, have a field name "Issue" and inside "Issue" I have many data in it. Everytime I add a new data in that document, it overwrites the data in the field. How to add the data without overwriting, please help.

Here is my code:

```
_saveIssueToActivities(dynamic data) async {
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
try {
  DocumentReference ref = db.collection('ACTIVITIES').document(user.uid);
  return ref.setData({
  'Issue': {
    'User_ID': '',
    'Name_ofUser': '${data['Name_ofUser']}',
    'Help_Description': '${data['Help_Description']}',
    'Help_DatePosted:': '',
    'Help_Location': '',
    'Help_TypeNeeded': '${data['Help_TypeNeeded']}',
    'Help_NotificationID': '',
  }
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

Here is my Database Structure:

[Link to my db pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBBpR.png)

Comment: You tried the merge: true optional parameter in the setData method?

Comment: yes sir marc, but it overwrites the old data, it wont add a new "Issue" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
Future<dynamic> addDataToFirestore(dynamic data) async {
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
DocumentReference ref = db.collection('ACTIVITIES').document(user.uid);
dynamic datatoSubmit = [{
    'User_ID': '',
    'Name_ofUser': '${data['Name_ofUser']}',
    'Help_Description': '${data['Help_Description']}',
    'Help_DatePosted:': '',
    'Help_Location': '',
    'Help_TypeNeeded': '${data['Help_TypeNeeded']}',
    'Help_NotificationID': ''
}];
   //Do some debugging with the datatypes or which type of data you have in the firebase document.

await ref.updateData({'Issue': FieldValue.arrayUnion(datatoSubmit)});

}


Or


Future<dynamic> addDataToFirestore(dynamic data) async {
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
DocumentReference ref = db.collection('ACTIVITIES').document(user.uid);
dynamic datatoSubmit = {
    'User_ID': '',
    'Name_ofUser': '${data['Name_ofUser']}',
    'Help_Description': '${data['Help_Description']}',
    'Help_DatePosted:': '',
    'Help_Location': '',
    'Help_TypeNeeded': '${data['Help_TypeNeeded']}',
    'Help_NotificationID': ''
};
   //Do some debugging with the datatypes or which type of data you have in the firebase document.

await ref.updateData({'Issue': FieldValue.arrayUnion(datatoSubmit)});

}
```

Here is my result with the 2nd one example :

[image]

Comment: Change your firebase Issue field data type to Array. So every time when you push it will add a new entry of data. or can you paste the output error here?

Comment: Still the same sir, this was the  message: I/flutter (11998): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Comment: Wrap the data you are sending to the firebase to a list. I have updated the code. As I mentioned in the comment debug the datatype. The issue is with the data type you are using in firebase and the data you are updating to firebase both are different.  This code is quite working fine for me.

Comment: Yeey it worked sir, but the problem  is if I have an empty document "updateData" wont work @@ first I need to use "setData" then "updataData" so that it will add a new one @@ how will I set a condition if the document is empty use setData but if not updateData @@ please help.